# Writing tests for a sidekiq worker

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, sidekiq, rspec-sidekiq

I am using the `rspec-sidekiq` gem (https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq) to help test a worker I am writing, but for some reason my test keeps failing.

Here is my Test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CommunicationWorker do
  it { should be_retryable false }

  it "enqueues a communication worker" do
    subject.perform("foo@bar.com", "bar@foo.com", [1,2,3])
    expect(CommunicationWorker).to have_enqueued_jobs(1)
  end
end
```

Here is the error:

```
 1) CommunicationWorker enqueues a communication worker
     Failure/Error: expect(CommunicationWorker).to have_enqueued_jobs(1)
       expected CommunicationWorker to have 1 enqueued job but got 0
     # ./spec/workers/communication_worker_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I based my low-level test off of their example on their wiki, but it's not working for me... any reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 32):

There are two things to test for here, the asynchronous enqueuing of the job in the queue and the execution of the job.

You can test the execution of the job by instantiating the job class and calling `perform()`.

You can test the enqueuing of the job by calling `perform_async()` on the job class.

To test the expectation in your test, you should be doing:

```
 it "enqueues a communication worker" do
    CommunicationWorker.perform_async("foo@bar.com", "bar@foo.com", [1,2,3])
    expect(CommunicationWorker).to have(1).jobs
  end
```

However, this is really just testing the Sidekiq framework and not a useful test.  I would recommend writing tests for the internal behavior of the job itself:

```
 it "enqueues a communication worker" do
    Widget.expects(:do_work).with(:some_value)
    Mailer.expects(:deliver)

    CommunicationWorker.new.perform("foo@bar.com", "bar@foo.com", [1,2,3])
  end
```

Comment: At the time this answer was given, I'm guessing `have_enqueued_jobs` was still valid but now the proper syntax is `have(1).jobs`

Comment: thank you! and for google: has_enqueued_job?
I found precisely zero results for that string

Comment: For rspec 3, this will work: 
`expect(CommunicationWorker.jobs.size).to eq(1)`

Answer (score 4):

What is the testing method? Try wrapping your existing test with `Sidekiq::Testing.fake! do <your code> end`. This will ensure the a fake queue is used. If sidekiq's testing methods is 'inline', the worker will be executed right away (and thus your queue will be 0 length).

Check out: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing for more info.